# Enabling directory indexing in one folder

Tags: apache

I can't manage httpd.conf in order to enable directory index in one specific folder:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
IndexIgnore *
```

```
<Directory "/srv/http/testsite/images">
Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `IndexIgnore *` this will *ignore* all files for indexing

Comment: Yep, but I set Allowoverride to rewrite and add +Indexes in options... is it wrong?

Comment: AllowOverride is used to determine which parameters may be overridden in a .htaccess file. It'll not undo settings set earlier in the config.

Comment: What I need to modify in the directory section of the directory to index then?

Answer (score 2):

What I think you want is:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/testsite/images">
  Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that this syntax is not correct. If it's specified "+Indexes" it should also be specified "+FollowSymLinks" - so, all starting with a plus. This is at least true in Apache/2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

It may also not be working depending on ~what~ you expect to be an index file... you should be able to add something this to your .htaccess as well

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.shtml index.php index.htm index.cfm index.cfml
```

I believe index.htm is NOT a default, may be what is missing.